# Insert,update delete in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I edited my question and heres the whole code i used

```
Public Class Form1
        Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'GradesDBDataSet.tblGrades' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            Me.TblGradesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.GradesDBDataSet.tblGrades)
        End Sub

        Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
            TblGradesBindingSource.MoveNext()

        End Sub
        Private Sub btnDelete_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
            TblGradesBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()

        End Sub

        Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
            TblGradesBindingSource.MovePrevious()

        End Sub

        Private Sub Button6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
            TblGradesBindingSource.MoveLast()

        End Sub

        Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
            TblGradesBindingSource.MoveFirst()

        End Sub

        Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            TblGradesBindingSource.AddNew()
        End Sub
        Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
            On Error GoTo saveErr
            TblGradesBindingSource.EndEdit()
            TblGradesTableAdapter.Update(GradesDBDataSet.tblGrades)
            MsgBox("Record Save ", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    saveErr:
            Exit Sub

        End Sub
    End Class
```

Hello Everyone... i have a problem using this code. . to save data to ms access from vb.net
i just follow a tutorial in youtube. it works BUT when i close the program then minutes later I run it again, data doesnt saved. . . Why? .

And can you suggest whats is the best way to Add, DELETE SAVE using vb.net? thanks eveyone ^_^

Comment: Can you post your complete code? It should work that way, so there's something wrong elsewhere.

Comment: Also, if using a connected relational database, why not use SQL's INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE action queries, of course after connecting via ODBC or OLEDB?

Comment: @Parfait, you should learn a bit about typed DataSets. The table adapter in the code already does exactly what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely answer is that you are using a local data file that is overwritten each time you build.

Read this to learn how local data files are managed:

http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246989(VS.80).aspx

The solution in that case is to select the data file in the Solution Explorer, open the Properties window and set the `Copy to output directory` property to `Copy if newer`.  The source file will only be copied to the output folder if you have changed that source file.  That means that you can keep your test data between sessions.

Comment: yeah . mr. Parfait . i wanted to used that SQL insert ,update and delete action. but unfortunately i dont know where to start . .

Comment: In future, if someone comments on your question and you want to reply to that comment, add your comment to the question too, not an answer that they haven't commented on.  In this case, ignore Parfait's comment.  You're already doing exactly what they suggested.  As for my answer, have you done as I suggested?  The code you already have should be working perfectly already and the only issue is that the database you are making changes to is getting overwritten each time you build, which means each time you make code changes and run.

Comment: ahmm . . sorry sir.. but may i ask if which here is the data file? .  is it the accdb or xsd? sorry. im really new to this . .

Comment: You should already know the answer to that question but, even if you don't, what is stopping you trying both?  You don't have to wait for others to think for you.

Comment: i tried what you said ,.. but unfortunately still got the problem.. anyway . . im thinking of using SQL Statements. i saw some code that uses SQL Statement. and it works . . now just I dont know where to start. i cant find tutorials how to make what they call Query Adapter, and SQl statements that is in the MODULE

Comment: You're already using SQL statements and there's no such thing as a Query Adapter.

Comment: On this line:  `TblGradesTableAdapter.Update(GradesDBDataSet.tblGrades)`; there are only three possible outcomes: 1) an exception is thrown; 2) the `Update` function returns zero; 3) the `Update` function returns a non-zero value.  Which is it in your case?  Get rid of that `On Error` line and, if you actually want to implement error handling, do it properly.